# AWS Load balancer causing slow API requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb

My API requests are extremely slow when called through https over my AWS elastic load balancer.  What's the best way to figure out exactly what I need to do to make my load balancer more efficient?  I'm using the load balancer specifically for HTTPs, and running an ec2 instance with an HTTP server behind it.

AWS elastic load balancer in eu-central-1a, eu-central-1b.
EC2 instance in eu-central-1a is a c5.xlarge which hosts an http server.

When I make API requests from the East Coast US to the load balancer via an HTTPS call, it works but it's horribly slow.  Best case scenario it's 400ms and it spikes up to 800-1500ms about 20% of the time.

When I make API requests from the East Coast US directly to the EC2 instance via HTTP totally bypassing the load balancer it's super quick.  Almost always 130-140ms and rarely spikes.

NOTE:  I'm using the load balancer for the HTTPS support only, I don't really care (right now) about actual load balancing across multiple backends.  For now, I just have one backend.  All of my incoming calls will be coming from the East Coast US and my server must stay in Europe for the time being.  So yes, I could move my server to the East Coast US so that calls are saying in one region, but I do not want to do that for various other reasons.

Questions and possible solutions:

- I chose an Application Load Balancer, is that right?
- How can I tell if my configuration is to blame for it being slow?
- Should I move my load balancer to East Coast US where the clients will be calling from? And leave the EC2 instance in eu-central-1a?
- My ec2 instance (c5.xlarge) has had absolutely nothing running in it except the http server so I know it's not getting overloaded with CPU and memory usage.  Is my instance type bad for being connected to a load balancer?

**Problem solved:**

- Got some help from a Dev ops guys. In Route 53 console, he removed the two A records that I created in the setup wizard and replaced them with a CNAME record direct to my alias. What was odd, the wizard wouldn't let me do that.  I had to use the "old version" of Route 53 where it let me type directly into the record.
- Performance is great now. The first request when it's establishing the secure connection takes a few hundred milliseconds, but every request after that is ~130ms.  And that's from East Coast US to Frankfurt Germany. Working as expected now.
- I tried moving my load balancer to another region, but AWS doesn't allow that.

Comment: If your users are all in us-east, can you move your service to a closer region? The Load Balancer shouldn't add too much delay, but there is no other obvious answer.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I will try that tomorrow. Is there any easy way to just move the load balancer to another region or do I have to create a new one and point it to the ec2 instance?

Comment: Remember that it's normal for HTTPS to require 2x the time required by HTTP for small payloads... so if your HTTP-only requires 140ms then your absolute best case theoretical time for HTTPS is 280ms.  You also need to review your load balancer logs because they'll tell you about timing between the balancer and EC2, which you need to understand before you can effectively troubleshoot.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It looks like I cannot select an Instance in another region under Step 5: Register Targets.  https://imgur.com/DygCKwF  Maybe it's not possible to put a load balancer in a different region than that of the EC2 instance?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone.  I've found the problem and listed the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

For the lowest latency you will want the shortest distance between the client and the servers, using [cloudping](https://www.cloudping.co/grid) I can see even directly between AWS regions on the AWS backbone (this is AWS private network) there is a latency of `95.22ms`. Over public internet this will be even more.

**If** you are unable to currently move the instances to another region, the performance of latency will still apply. However, I would suggest taking a look at CloudFront which is the AWS CDN service.

> The Amazon CloudFront content delivery network (CDN) is massively scaled and globally distributed. The CloudFront network has 216 points of presence (PoPs), and leverages the highly-resilient Amazon backbone network for superior performance and availability for your end users.

A major feature of CloudFront is providing local caching of front end objects (images, css, static HTML), if you can cache any of these objects your users experience will significantly improve. Many sites will use this service to cache many static or rarely changing parts of their site such as the homepage.

If parts of static page are dynamic, can you look at loading them asynchronously after initial page load? This gives the user the perception the site is loading whilst parts of the page are still loading afterwards.

You will also gain the benefit of performance improvements made to CloudFront such as its utilization of the AWS backbone to gain improved latency between the users PoP location and the target endpoint.

A couple of links that might be interesting for you:

- [AWS Infrastructure Map](https://infrastructure.aws/)
- [AWS re:Invent 2019: Optimizing for performance in CloudFront: Every millisecond counts!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DeygvViFlXQ)

Comment: I'm not a dev ops expert, so forgive my dumb question.  Are you suggesting I have Amazon CloudFront handle the https for me and point to my ec2 instance and get better performance?  Amazon CloudFront says it uses Elastic Load Balancing, so wouldn't I get the same result using it?

Comment: You would add it in front of your Load Balancer endpoint, leave the ELB as it is. It just brings first contact closer to the customer, and reduces the latency as CloudFront will use the AWS private network to communicate with the ELB rather than your customers internet. It also has a few built in mechanisms to improve speed, the video attached includes some more examples of under the hood if it interests you. But from your perspective you simply point your DNS at the CloudFront distribution instead of your ELB. The ELB becomes the origin in the configuration in CloudFront

Comment: So I created a CloudFront Distribution and pointed it to my load balancer, it generates a url like https://<randomStuffHere>.cloudfront.net/, when I type that into a browser it redirects and loads just fine.  But when I make the same exact call in postman it fails with a 403 ERROR.  Am I configuring this wrong?  I have my configuration set so that https is enabled and Allowed HTTP Methods = GET, HEAD.  I'm only making GET calls.  Any ideas why my simple GET wouldn't work in postman but would in chrome web browser?

All settings default except -> Origin Protocol Policy = Match Viewer

Comment: It will normally give you HTML explaining why? Do you have the output of the HTML? :)

Comment: I just sent you an email (to the email address in your stackoverflow account) with the details so I can share more easily without having to worry about privacy.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I greatly appreciate the time you spent helping me.  The problem ended up being my A records in Route 53 console.  The solution is listed above.